# Python KeyError: '\n'

Tags: python, keyerror

I use the script below for molecular barcode extraction from fastq files. However, I keep getting the following key error.

```
File "extractMolecularBarcode.py", line 42, in <module>
    dicoBarcode[barcode] += 1
KeyError: '\n'
```

I know the key error means something is not defined in the dictionary, but I can't figure out the problem. Could you help please? Thank you so much!

Here is the script:

```
import sys, itertools


iFastq=open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
oFastq=open(sys.argv[2], 'w')
oBarcode=open(sys.argv[3], 'w')
oLigation=open(sys.argv[4], 'w')

dicoBarcode={}
dicoLigation={}
nct='ACTGN'
for barcode in list(itertools.product(nct, repeat=6)):
    dicoBarcode["".join(barcode)] = 0
    dicoLigation["".join(barcode)] = 0


header= iFastq.readline().rstrip()
while header != '':
    totseq= iFastq.readline()
    plus = iFastq.readline()
    qual = iFastq.readline()
    barcode = totseq[0:6]
    ligation = totseq[3:9]
    seq = totseq[6:]
    oFastq.write(header.split(" ")[0]+'_MolecularBarcode:'+barcode+' '+header.split(" ")[1]+'\n')
    oFastq.write(seq)
    oFastq.write(plus)
    oFastq.write(qual[6:])
    header= iFastq.readline().rstrip()

    dicoBarcode[barcode] += 1
    if len(seq) >= 4 :
    dicoLigation[ligation] += 1

for barcode, times in dicoBarcode.items():
oBarcode.write("%s\t%s\n" % (barcode, str(times)))

for ligation, times in dicoLigation.items():
oLigation.write("%s\t%s\n" % (ligation, str(times)))
```

Answer (score 3):

you have a newline in your file which when you use

```
 dicoBarcode[barcode] += 1
```

the **barcode value is a newline** or '\n' which causes an error!

you can either get over it by providing a default value:

```
discoBarcode.get(barcode,YOURDEFAULT)
```

or you can first remove newlines then process file ;)

```
yourfile.readline().rstrip("\n")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And do you have any suggestion to eliminate this problem?

Comment: I couldn't understand the one with dicobarcode.get(barcode, yourdefault). Could you explain it a little bit more? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not calling `rstrip()` on the actual line where your `barcode` value comes from. You need to edit these lines:

```
totseq= iFastq.readline()
plus = iFastq.readline()
qual = iFastq.readline()
```

So that they look like this:

```
totseq= iFastq.readline().rstrip()
plus = iFastq.readline().rstrip()
qual = iFastq.readline().rstrip()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried rstrip when I was looking for an answer about key error in other questions, but it still gives me the same error :/

Comment: `KeyError` just means that that particular key `\n` is not in your dictionary, so the read/increment fails. I tried to solve the original problem.

Comment: I have tried it again to add \n in both rstrip (the one before the start of 'while' and the one at the end of the 'while' loop). It didn't work. It gives me the same error again. In the prior step, I did adapter removal. Maybe there was a problem in that step leading to this error?

Comment: @mordel I'm sorry I was mistaken on 2 counts. Edited the answer. 1. `rstrip()` DOES remove `\n` and 2. you get your barcode value from another `readline()` that does not have `rstrip`

Comment: I added rstrip to the end of those three rows (totseq, plus and qual) as you suggested. Still nothing changed :(